# cronjob to run java program

Tags: java, cron

I am trying to run a java program using cronjob, let's suppose it is the `HelloWorld` example.
When I do `which java` I get the following path `/opt/java/bin/java` and when I try to the program in the cronjob it does not run, I think cronjob can not see the absolute path of java because when I do the following:

```
* * * * * /opt/java/bin/java -help > /absolute/path/to/file.txt
```

or the following

```
* * * * * /opt/java/bin/java HelloWorld > /absolute/path/to/file.txt
```

I get an empty file as a result. cronjob runs because I get the file.txt created and java also works because I can run my HelloWorld manually using the absolute path of java.

Comment: Use `2>&1` to pipe standard error too. If mail is working you should have gotten a mail with the output.

Comment: thank you, that's pretty helpful, I can the error messages now in my file, I can see the output of `java -help` so cron job can see the bsolute path of java actually, and I see that I have exceptions in my program : P

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: It would be helpful to the others if you convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: @RodwanBakkar Welcome to the wonderful world of writing production hardened code 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, output from a cronjob is normally mailed to the user which the cronjob runs as.  So if your mailsystem is correctly configured (you can run `date | mail $(whoami)` and then read that mail) you should see what your program prints when run.  That mail is sent if the program creates any output.  If no output is created, no mail is sent.

Also note that `program > out.log` only redirects standard output.  If you do not want standard error to keep going in the mail, you can redirect it with `program 2> err.log`.   If you want both to go in the same output file use `program > out.log 2>&1`.   All this is standard Unix so you can use any system administration book on Linux to learn more.